# Shiny HTML full page Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I am begining in styling shiny apps.

I want to create a create a full screen slider into a tabpanel of my application for my landing page.

According to [this](https://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/RPOXya) snippet, here's my application.

The carousel is empty. How can I solve this issues (perhaps the inline css   `<div class="item active" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=697);">` not working?

```
library(shiny)
   ui <- fluidPage(includeCSS("carousel.css"),
       navbarPage("project",
                 collapsible = TRUE,
                 tabPanel("Home",
                          tags$div(HTML('<div class="tcb-bs-fullscreen">
                            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel       slide carousel-bg" data-ride="carousel">
                            <!-- Indicators -->
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=697);">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                            ...
                          </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=545);">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                            ...
                          </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=673);">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                            ...
                          </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Controls -->
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            </div>')
          )
       )
     )
    )

    # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
    server <- function(input, output) {}

    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And the LESS css:

```
        /****************************
        TURN BOOTSTRAP CAROUSEL INTO FULL SCREEN SLIDER
        *****************************/
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%; 
        }
        .tcb-bs-fullscreen{
            height: 100%;
            .carousel,
            .item,
            .active {
                height: 100%;
            }
            .carousel-inner {
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
        /****************************
        USE BACKGROUND IMAGES IN CAROUSEL SLIDER
        *****************************/
        .carousel-bg {
            .carousel-inner {
                .item {
                    background-color: darkslategrey;
                    background-size: cover;
                    background-position: center;
                    min-height: 360px;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Wilcar, have you tried dividing your codes in segments, so that you could figure out what is causing the problem in your code and where this would happen? See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (divide and conquer). I notice that you generate a lot of HTML dynamically, maybe you would first like to get that to work.

Comment: @Barrosy Thank you for advise. I think I can't use inline css

Comment: I was not talking about the use of inline CSS. What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: shiny is using bootstrap 3

Comment: What do you mean by `"The carousel is empty"`? If you mean that the two other images are not being loaded, that is because the URL's are dead or not containing your image (`<div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=673);">` of which `https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=673` might be dead).

Comment: Just FYI: library([slickR](https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/slickR)) provides an easy to implement alternative. Also see the [examples](https://metrumresearchgroup.github.io/slickR/).

Answer (score 1):

The URL's of the images loaded within your carousel seem dead except for the second or middle URL:

Does not load:

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=697);">
```

Does load:

```
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=545);">
```

Does not load:

```
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=673);">
```

The code is working fine (you might want to fix your CSS however):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.tcb-bs-fullscreen {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel, .item, .active {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-bg .carousel-inner .item {
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 360px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="tcb-bs-fullscreen">
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>

   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=697" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
   ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=545" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
   ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1600/840?image=673" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
   ...
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/423n5ef6/)